# Given that $(I-A)^k=0$, is A invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $(I-A)^k=0$ for some positive integer $k$. Can we claim that $A$ is invertible?

Comment: Can you find a way to write $AB=I$ for some suitable $B$ (*which may or may not look incredibly complicated and have something to do with $A$ itself*)?

Comment: @JMoravitz nice hint! I think I have proved this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**  The binomial theorem **for real numbers** states that:

$$(x+y)^k = \sum\limits_{i=0}^k \binom{k}{i}x^iy^{k-i}$$

Can you come up with something similar involving $(I+A)^k$ for matrices?

(*why doesn't the generic binomial theorem work for arbitrary matrices $(A+B)^k$?*)

Can you use what you've discovered to write $AB=I$ for some suitable choice of $B$?

What would this imply about the existence of $A^{-1}$?

Answer (score 1):

a matrix $M$ is called nilpotent if there is a $k$ for which $M^k=0$.

it is easily proved that if $M$ is nilpotent then $I-M$ has an inverse. just use the formal series:
$$
(I-M)^{-1} = 1 + M + M^2 + ...
$$
and note that this terminates after a finite number of terms.

Now, the question states that the matrix $M=I-A$ is nilpotent, hence $I-M$ has an inverse. but $I-M$ is just $A$

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proof for $\mathbb{C}$:

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $(1-\lambda)^k$ is an eigenvalue of $(I-A)^k$ and hence $(1-\lambda)^k = 0$. In particular, $\lambda \neq 0$, and
hence $A$ is invertible.